# Python 2.x and Python 3.x with Beautiful Soup Package on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Tags: macos, installation, python, libraries

I am fairly new to Python and have run into some problems installing Beautiful Soup.  I am running Mac OSX 10.9.5.

I installed and used Python 3.4 during a summer and installed Beautiful Soup 4 for a project.  That installation worked fine.  I am now needing to use Python 2.7 with Beautiful Soup.  Suspecting that I would need to install a different version of Beautiful Soup I went ahead and ran my Python code to be sure.  When my code tries to import bs4 I get an error. Call and error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

However, when I try to install Beautiful Soup from the console within PyCharm where I am using Python 2.7 the installation fails:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied
```

I also tried to install from a new terminal window opened from the Python 2.7 folder in hope that the install would be focused there.  Same result:

```
 MacBook-Pro-i7:Python 2.7 InnoVition$ pip install beautifulsoup4
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Is there some way I can temporarily "hide" the bs4 installation associated with Python 3.4 so the installation to Python 2.7 can proceed?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: I have found a work-around to the problem.  I placed the bs4 folder from the install package in the same folder with my project files.  Not very clean, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the Python 2.7 `site-packages` is, you could set a variable like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/my-path-to/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Perhaps you also could try `virtualenv` package in order to have different Python versions working really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have solved the problem.  I placed the bs4 folder from the install package in the same folder with my project files.  Not very clean, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to run beautifulsoup in python2.7, you will need to install bs3 instead of bs4.  bs3 is designed for a python2.7 environment.